# How to fix gnome terminal search function - it doesn't find anything

Tags: command-line, terminal, mate-desktop, ubuntu-mate, mate-terminal

After upgrading my system, my MATE version is 1.24.0; the previous version was 1.22.2.

When I use the mate-terminal and try the Search function (ctrl+shift+f) and search for a word or string, it doesn't find or highlight anything as like there is no match. Prior to the upgrade, it was finding and highlighting string or part of a string that is searched for and currently somewhere in the shell.

Comment: Please file a separate question for every issue you have. As for your first issue: Do you use gnome-terminal or mate-terminal? If gnome-terminal then mate's version is irrelevant, what is your gnome-terminal version? If mate-terminal then please edit the post (including the tags) to fix this.

Comment: When I go in control center-> Preferred Application - > System - > and the Terminal dropdown menu I have 4 options UXTerm, Mate-terminal, Root Terminal, Xterm.  Also in synaptic I have installed mate-terminal and mate-terminal-common. If i search gnome-terminal there is nothing installed under that.
So I guess I have Mate-terminal not gnome-terminal correct?

Comment: I have edited my tags, will my question now appear on the right people? I mean I have asked my question before 4 hours with the other tags and now its not in the New questions, will it be seen

Comment: @egmont I have edited the question properly and asked the second thing in another thread. Although both these questions are connected

Comment: Your post still says you use gnome-terminal, whereas you don't. I could have perhaps helped with gnome-terminal, but cannot with mate-terminal, sorry, hopefully someone will help you out.

Comment: @egmont I made the edit and changed it to mate-terminal. 
Can you try to help me, maybe the solution for a gnome-terminal can be applied to mate-terminal. If we find out the soultion you can write it as a answer and i will accept it. Because looks like there aren't any volunteers to help

Comment: Similar issues here. Not sure how to find the version of Gnome terminal, but unless "Match entire word only" is checked, entire word matches are not found at all, and different occurrences are found depending in which direction the search is carried out, and some strings are never found.

Comment: Update on my similar issues comment: I switched to Konsole, which worked fine.